# CSS Splash unable to center the image on every size

Tags: css

I have a splash image that loads with my software when the page loads.

At the current size of the window which is 1024px the image is loading centred but when make the window start maximised it's too much to the left.

Here is my css:

```
#splash {
  width: 700px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 14% 14%;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

#splash img {
  width: 700px;
  height: auto;
}
```

How can I change this css so that it loads centred at any window size?

Comment: change your `margin: 14% 14%;` to `margin: 14% auto;` The reason it's too far to the left, is you set the margin to `14%` so it will always be 14% to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code needs tidying up a bit. Look at this updated fiddle I did for you which has some improvements that solve your issue: https://jsfiddle.net/Ly06krt3/29

You need to do:

```
#splash {
   max-width: 700px;
   height: auto;
   line-height: 50px;
   margin: 0 auto;  
   box-sizing: border-box;
   text-align: center;
   z-index: 1;
   width: 100%;
}

#splash img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

to center a `div`. I have added a `max-width` to the `#splash` ID; this will give it a fixed width until the browser gets to that point, which will then resize because of the `width: 100%`.

You need to also make the code more responsive friendly. So adding a percentage width to the img will give it that fluidity when resizing the browser.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the splash exactly centered, it's a simple matter of applying a negative top margin of half the images height, and a negative left margin of half the images width. For this example, like so:
Add this css to your splash.

```
 .centered {
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      /* bring your own prefixes */
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#splash {
  width: 700px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -350px;
  margin-top: -25px;
}

#splash img {
  width: 700px;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you want the loader to be in center of a page i.e responsive. Here I have tried which always remains center;

```css
.loader{
  background-color:red;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:absolute;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  animation:pulse 0.2s infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
   0% { transform: scale(1); }
   50% { transform: scale(1.1); }
   100% { transform: scale(1); } 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="loader"></div>
</body>
</html>
```